# Twitter API automatically (randomly?) removes my access token and revokes app

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, twitter

I'm using a simple app i wrote in python 2.7 to tweet, follow, and unfollow people on twitter when i'm not at a console using my own app that i've given access to my own account. I've done the 3-legged process of sending the token, gaining the pin, and then finally acquiring the access key and secret. I can follow, and tweet without a hitch. However, for some reason, seemingly randomly (I've gone complete days without hitting the problem, to hitting it every 10 min or so) I try to unfollow someone only to be greeted with a "Invalid or expired token, code 89, status 401" message. I'll then go online to find out that my access key is no longer existent, and then i'll go to my twitter profile settings only to find that my app has been automatically revoked access somehow. There is no message or warning label or email or anything from twitter saying I've been rate limited or suspended, and I can (and have) gone through the 3-legged process again to verify and gain a new access key. And then the process repeats again.
Does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Comment: I've also started a thread here in hopes of solving this mystery https://twittercommunity.com/t/oauth-token-expires-and-my-app-access-gets-revoked-randomly-why/61281/4

Comment: Facing the same issue. It seems like twitter deletes the access token when the app performs many operations. Moreover the account that had this issue was also shadow-banned, I guess it's somehow related.